# will limit work same for both condition in select and delete statement

Tags: mysql, sql

i have to pick unused items from a table, move those items with other info to used table that will be called `useditems`. while items finally moved i have to delete those items from unused table.

so i have write down following query .

```
INSERT INTO USED select KNumber from unused limit 1000;
DELETE FROM unused limit 1000;
```

my only concern point is that its always pick the same record as i am not using any order by  in query and in table i have only single column . so only inserted records will be deleted.

i am new with mysql .

Answer (score 1):

Instead use a `order by` clause with `limit` clause to make sure the same picking of records and limit with out order by won't make much sense cause only with limit you may end up inserting/deleting a different set off data whereas your goal is to delete the same set of data which you are inserting.

```
INSERT INTO USED select KNumber from unused order by KNumber limit 1000;

DELETE FROM unused order by KNumber limit 1000;
```

Comment: i have only one column in both table and which is character type . so i have doubt that if i used order by then its surely slow down my complete query .

Comment: @rahularyansharma, that depends on the number of rows and whether that column have index on it or not. I don't think your speed will be compromised. Moreover, you will be sure that the same record getting deleted which are inserted as well. give it a try and see for yourself.

Comment: @Downvoter, don't just down vote, let people know the reason as well.

Comment: Using order by is the only way to maintain data integrity. It doesn't matter if the query is slower, not using it is a recipe for disaster as databases are not guaranteed to ever return records in a specific order not even the order they are stored in. If the field is not indexed, it should be.

Answer (score 0):

To be sure of the approach, you can delete those records that you put already in the USED table:

```
Delete from Unused 
    where kNumber in (
        select distinct kNumber from Used
        )
```

Comment: used already have a lots of records and its have only a single column .

Comment: But as I understood, a record cannot be in both tables. Once it is inserted in the "USED" table, it should be deleted from "Unused". So the above code (that runs after your select statement) works. Right?

Answer (score 0):

Write an `insert` trigger on `Used` that deletes from `Unused` based on the data being inserted.

```
drop trigger if exists used_ai;
delimiter //
CREATE trigger used_ai after insert on used
for each row
begin
    delete from Unused where kNumber = New.kNumber;
end//
delimiter ;
```